# how to move the +- errors estimates to another column with pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

so i have a pandas dataframe that looks like this :

[image]

is there a way to move the errors in Ep and Sbolo to  two other column without having to do it by hand? thank you

Comment: please share data as text rather than pictures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `str.split`:

```
df[['sb1', 'sb2']] = (df['S Bolo'].str.split('\s*\u00b1\s*', expand=True)
                                  .apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce'))
print(df)

# Output
         S Bolo    sb1   sb2
0  17.90 ± 0.13  17.90  0.13
1   4.43 ± 0.08   4.43  0.08
```

The [unicode value](https://www.compart.com/fr/unicode/U+00B1) of `±` is U+00B1 and do the same for other column.